# unable get def function working in python flask

Tags: python, flask

i am creating a login system and i want to make a function which redirect user to login page if session of login is false.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, session
import json
from db import database

def login_require():
    if session.get('islogin') != True:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'secret key for session'

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    if session.get('islogin') == True:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    else:
        return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/rishtedar')
def rishtedar():
    login_require()
    return render_template('rishtedar.html')
```

in above code function login_require() not redirect to login page

Comment: What's "not working"? Are there any errors? If so, please edit in the full traceback. Also, please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: when i visit custom page it is not redirect to login page

Comment: @GrowUpAnand Which custom page?

Comment: when i visit /rishtedar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def login_require():
    if session.get('islogin') != True:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

@app.route('/rishtedar')
def rishtedar():
    login_require()
    return render_template('rishtedar.html')
```

The `return` in `login_require()` sends the value (in this case a redirect response) back to where you call it, but that line does nothing with the return value. Instead, your code continues to call `render_template()` and return the response.

You need to find a way to use the return value from `login_require()`:

```
@app.route('/rishtedar')
def rishtedar():
    required = login_require()
    if required:
       return required
    return render_template('rishtedar.html')
```

This solution uses your `login_require()` function as it is. An alternative solution is to pass a function to `login_require()` that returns the response on success:

```
def login_require(get_response):
    if session.get('islogin'): # Never compare "== True" or "!= True"
        return get_response()
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

@app.route('/rishtedar')
def rishtedar():
    def get_response():
        return render_template('rishtedar.html')
    return login_require(get_response)
```

This version is very nice because it begins your journey towards decorators. I suggest you read up on these because they provide an elegant syntax to conveniently modify a function's behavior without lots of repetition. Once you understand the concept, you can create a `@login_require` decorator that works similar to the `@app.route()` decorator you already use.

Comment: can you please suggest to create a similar function which i use to do check login and redirect user to login page

Comment: thanks for help please check my updated function in question if it is correct.

Comment: Yes, your solution works. However, you should post it as an answer instead of editing your original question.

Comment: @GrowUpAnand Note: There was a typo in my answer. I forgot to put `return` in the `get_response()` method.

Comment: @GrowUpAnand Also, your solution requires that all responses after a login call `render_template()`. If you need to return a response from a different function, you will have to do something more like my second example that calls another function to return the response. As I said in my answer, you should learn more about decorators because they are the next logical step from this example.